# Apache - mod_perl : Unknown Authz provider 'access'

Tags: apache-2.4, perl, mod-perl

I am trying to set up and run an old Web application(written in 2010) in a new Linux environment. The Apache server is not starting because of the error `Unknown Authz provider access`, caused by the configuration given below.

```
<Directory /srv/webapp>
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "3 Months"
    AuthType security::AuthCookieHandler
    AuthName Maxio
    PerlAuthenHandler security::AuthCookieHandler->authenticate
    PerlAuthzHandler security::AuthCookieHandler->authorize
    require access
</Directory>
```

I couldn't find any documentation for this, or any apache module that defines `access` , but `security::AuthCookieHandler` has

```
sub access
{
...
...
}
```

I understand that this is `mod_perl` based authentication, but haven't worked on this before. Apache starts if this authentication is disabled, and the application loads in the browser.

So the questions are

1. Is `require access` supposed to get the return value from `sub access` ?
2. If so, why `sub access` is not visible to the configuration ?
3. If not so, what is `access` here ?

Answer (score 1):

After researching for a few hours I found out that this is because of the changes in the latest versions of Apache and mod_perl.

From the following docs,

https://metacpan.org/release/Apache-AuthCookie
https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Apache-AuthCookie/README.apache-2.4.pod

I understood that Apache 2.4 needs mod_perl version 2.0.9 or higher.

Also custom Authz Provider has to be added using `PerlAddAuthzProvider`

So I was able to solve it by writing

```
PerlAddAuthzProvider access security::AuthCookieHandler->access
...
...
<Directory /srv/webapp>
    ...
    ...
    require access
</Directory>
```